# ruby still shows old version

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm, osx-leopard, ruby-2.0

I have installed or I think is is so a new version of ruby on my osx ppc running leopard 10.5.8 but when I run `ruby --version it shows the old one 1.8.7` (default on the machine) but when I run...

```
find /usr -type f -name \*.rb
```

it shows ruby2.0.o is on:

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.0.0/
```

with all its `.rb` files.

But when I check using `locate ruby`

it shows the version 1.8.7 under

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby
```

Anytime I check on `ruby --version` it shows the 1.8.7...how can I change that?

Totally newbie...thanks.

BTW rvm is not installing by anychance or homebrew and My xcode doesn't have downloads.

Answer (score 14):

I installed it with `brew install ruby` and it still showed the original Mac version (2.3) too. The following commands fixed it:

First check if Ruby is still pointed to the original location:

```
which ruby
# /usr/bin/ruby
```

Change this to the new location.

```
export PATH=/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH
which ruby
# /usr/local/opt/ruby/bin/ruby
```

Check if you have the new version

```
ruby -v
# ruby 2.6.5p114 (2019-10-01 revision 67812) [x86_64-darwin18]
```

Solved it!

Comment: I was also getting same issue.. setting PATH manually solved this issue.

Answer (score 10):

After running in circles trying to reinstall `rvm` and `ruby`, what did it for me was simply changing the default ruby version used by `rvm`:

Try running **rvm list**

In my case I had

```
=* ruby-2.1.1 [ x86_64 ]
ruby-2.1.4 [ x86_64 ]
ruby-2.2.2 [ x86_64 ]
```

After running **rvm --default use 2.2.2**, I had the correct ruby version:

```
ruby-2.1.1 [ x86_64 ]
ruby-2.1.4 [ x86_64 ]
=* ruby-2.2.2 [ x86_64 ]
```

See https://rvm.io/rubies/default

Answer (score 8):

Most of the systems today search for programs to run using `PATH` environment variable. If you did install ruby in `/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.0.0/` then you should modify your `PATH` accordingly:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.0.0/bin:$PATH"
```

as for problems with any software you should report the problems you are facing:

- `homebrew` - https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues
- `rvm` - https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues

Comment: Thanks man, I've downloaded using curl the Tigerbrew, which is the leopard g5 and g4 version for homebrew and for that I have to uninstall git and change the path, at the .profile page using text editor...thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found on [Mac Install Guide](https://mac.install.guide/ruby/13.html) that you have to add the following to your `.zshrc` file:

```
if [ -d "/opt/homebrew/opt/ruby/bin" ]; then
  export PATH=/opt/homebrew/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH
  export PATH=`gem environment gemdir`/bin:$PATH
fi
```

This is the only solution that worked for me.