# Mac Mini - MacOS Sonoma 14.2.1 and Apple M1 chip. error: CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/Database":

Tags: ios, flutter, cocoapods, apple-m1, macos-sonoma

```
-Mac-mini ios % arch -x86_64 pod update
Update all pods
Updating local specs repositories
Analyzing dependencies
firebase_auth: Using Firebase SDK version '10.18.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
firebase_core: Using Firebase SDK version '10.18.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
firebase_database: Using Firebase SDK version '10.18.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/Database":
  In Podfile:
    firebase_database (from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_database/ios`) was resolved to 10.3.8, which depends on
      Firebase/Database (= 10.18.0)

    flutter_geofire (from `.symlinks/plugins/flutter_geofire/ios`) was resolved to 0.0.1, which depends on
      GeoFire (~> 4.0) was resolved to 4.1.0, which depends on
        Firebase/Database (~> 6.0)
-Mac-mini ios % arch -x86_64 pod install
Analyzing dependencies
firebase_auth: Using Firebase SDK version '10.18.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
firebase_core: Using Firebase SDK version '10.18.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
firebase_database: Using Firebase SDK version '10.18.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/Database":
  In Podfile:
    firebase_database (from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_database/ios`) was resolved to 10.3.8, which depends on
      Firebase/Database (= 10.18.0)

    flutter_geofire (from `.symlinks/plugins/flutter_geofire/ios`) was resolved to 0.0.1, which depends on
      GeoFire (~> 4.0) was resolved to 4.1.0, which depends on
        Firebase/Database (~> 6.0)
```

I already tried so many things. These are the details

https://stackify.com/install-ruby-on-your-mac-everything-you-need-to-get-going/
[ruby still shows old version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15576929/ruby-still-shows-old-version)

https://stackify.com/install-ruby-on-your-mac-everything-you-need-to-get-going/

Need to build my flutter project, not able to build because of above error.

Comment: Following might help you : https://stackoverflow.com/a/62042932/4373661

Comment: i tried the mentioned link solutions.  i deleted the podlock file and ran again pod update. I am still stuck with the same issue.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi, I am exactly getting the below mentioned error, while building the ios flutter project in my mac os.[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/Database":
  In Podfile:
    firebase_database (from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_database/ios`) was resolved to 10.3.8, which depends on
      Firebase/Database (= 10.18.0)

    flutter_geofire (from `.symlinks/plugins/flutter_geofire/ios`) was resolved to 0.0.1, which depends on
      GeoFire (~> 4.0) was resolved to 4.1.0, which depends on
        Firebase/Database (~> 6.0)